# Direct Product of a Clean Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, direct-product, ring-homomorphism

Commutative rings whose elements are a sum of an unit and idempotent by Anderson & Camillo (2002)

**Definition 1.**
A commutative ring $R$ is a clean ring if every element $x\in R$ can be written in the form of $x=u+i$ where $u\in U(R)$ and i$\in Id(R)$.

**Proposition 2.**
(1) A quasilocal ring is a clean ring.
(2) A homomorphic image of a clean ring is a clean ring.
(3) A direct product $R=∏R_α $ of rings $\{R_α\}$ is a clean ring if and only if each $R_\alpha$ is a clean ring.
**Proof**.
(2) This is immediate since the homomorphic image of a unit (resp., idempotent) is a unit (resp., idempotent).
(3) ($\Rightarrow$) This follow from (2).

How does the proof of (3) to the right is follow from (2)? Is there any relationship between direct product and homomorphic image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $R=\prod R_\alpha$ is clean, the image of the projection homomorphism $\pi_\alpha:R\to R_\alpha$ is a clean ring by (2). The projection is surjective, so $R_\alpha$ is clean.

Answer (score 0):

Only half of 3 follows "immediately" from 2.

Each $R_\alpha$ is of course the homomorphic image of $R$ by projecting onto the coordinate $\alpha$.

The remaining thing to do is to prove that the product is clean if the $R_\alpha$ are all clean.

But this is easy to see because an idempotent in the product is an element whose entries are idempotent, and a unit in the product is an element whose entries are units.

In fact, knowing that, you don't even need $2$ to show $3$: it is more or less obvious that a clean element of the product is an element whose entries are clean elements of the factors.

Comment: If its "almost clean ring" case, does the homomorphic image of a regular element is a regular?

Comment: @chandara The answer to that is so obvious I insist you complete it as an exercise yourself.

Comment: @chandara I don't know if I need to highlight this, but I am not saying your conjecture is correct.

Comment: I just figured out that there is homomorphism from $Z$ to $Z_6 $ that maps regular element into zero divisor. But I'm still confuse with the proof in the case of almost clean ring.

Comment: @chandara You completed the exercise I had in mind!  I have no idea about the almost-clean case, and I wasn’t suggesting it was obvious.